# Excel - How to convert 4 Hex numbers (16 bits) to 2 Hex number (8 bits)?

Tags: hexadecimal

How do I convert from a hex value (FACE) to (CE) in Excel?

I tried Dec2Hex (64206,4) -- I got FACE which is ok.
I tried Dec2Hex (64206,3) -- I got #NUM! which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your truncating, not converting.

=mid(a1,3,2)

where a1 contains FACE

Answer (score 1):

(You probably mean `Dec2Hex`.)

`Dec2Hex(64206,4)` gives you `FACE`, because you asked for four places in the result.

`Dec2Hex(64206,3)` gives you an error (I would expect #NUM!, not #VALUE!), because you asked for only three places in the result, but 64206 (decimal) is FACE (hex), so it can't be represented in only three places.

You can see this visually if you try `Dec2Hex(64206,5)`, which gives you `0FACE`, because it pads the result out to five places with a leading zero.

To "convert" FACE to CE, you can either truncate as the answer from cybernard indicates, which is a text-based solution, or you can use a bitmask to keep only the lower 8 bits, which is a math-based solution. For example:

`BitAnd(64206,255)` gives `206` which then gives you `CE` when you run it through `Dec2Hex`.

Comment: Doug - Thank you very much. The BitAnd works for me. You right I mean Dec2Hex and #NUM! is the error.